# Handle exception in JavaMailSender

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail

I created simple MailService to send content by email. It works but I don't know how to handle exceptions (my idea is to print some info in HTML view or redirect on 404 page)

MailService:

```
public class MailService {

    public final JavaMailSender emailSender;


    public void sendMail(String content, String to, Boolean isHtml, String subject, String path) {

        log.debug("Send e-mail[multipart '{}' and html '{}'] to '{}' with subject '{}' and content={}",
                true, isHtml, to, subject, content);

        MimeMessage mimeMessage = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
        try {
            MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, CharEncoding.UTF_8);
            message.setTo(to);
            message.setFrom("applica@applica.ai");
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(content, isHtml);
            FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(path);
            message.addAttachment(file.getFilename(), file);
            emailSender.send(mimeMessage);
            log.debug("Sent e-mail to User '{}'", to);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("E-mail could not be sent to user '{}'", to, e);

        }
    }

}
```

Usage in Controller:

```
        try {
        mailService.sendMail(templateEngine.process("summary/mailTemplate", ctx), userInfo.getEmail(), true, "Mail title", "attachment title);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "redirect:/404";
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created service to handle logic of mail exception

```
public class MailSendingException extends Exception {

    public MailSendingException() {
    }

    public MailSendingException(String s) {
        super(s);
    }
}
```

and controller for this specific view

```
@Controller
public class errorMailController {

    @GetMapping("/errorMail")
    public String errorMail() {
        return "errorMail";
    }
}
```

and then I used it in place where I'm sending email

```
 try {
        mailService.sendMail(templateEngine.process("summary/mailTemplate", ctx), userInfo.getEmail(), true, "Mail title", "attachment title);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "redirect:/404";
        }
         catch (MailSendingException mse) {
            return "redirect:/errorMail";
        }
```